# Select a cell if condition met

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to write a code to select a cell if the condition is met. After trying to run my code, the result is my code working but it didn't select the corresponding rows

Could you please help me to deduct what is a problem with my code?

Thank you

```
Sub AnalysisNote()

'1. Copy the client's name and its note ranked by 4 particular conditions (20;17-20;15-17;11-15;<11)

Dim finalrow As Long, i As Long
Dim clientnote As Range 'find
Const startrowb As Byte = 6
Dim c As Byte

c = 9
finalrow = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
Set clientnote = ShNote.Rows(startrowb).Find _
(What:=ShNote.Cells(startrowb, c).Value, LookIn:=xlValues, MatchCase:=False, lookat:=xlWhole)


For i = startrowb To finalrow
    If clientnote.Value = 20 Then
        Range(Cells(i, c)).Select
    End If
Next i

End Sub
```

I expect that my macro will find the value 20 on column "I" and select it.

p.s: I have several values "20" on column I

Comment: Thank you for your quick reply. I want to write a code that loop through my column "I" to find these values (20; 17-20 ;15-17 ;11-15 ;<11). After finding these values, I want macro to copy automatically the client's name and the corresponding values to another sheet.

Comment: Why declare `c` and `startrowb` as `Byte` instead of `Long`?

Comment: Because it only to choose the number of column

Comment: You are also using in your `Find`.  You will exceed the number available (255).  There are more than 16,000 columns and over 1 million rows.  Best to use `Long`.

Comment: @C.Edo Are you expecting to select all the cells that have value 20 with this loop ? Select with this loop will only select the last cell where it matches your condition.

Comment: I think a filter will accomplish what you need, without have to `Select`.

Comment: FYI - technically, you don't need this loop.  Selecting cells doesn't do anything really, so you could replace that with `If clientNote.value = 20 then Cells(finalRow,c).Select`.  (...but why are you selecting a cell in the end?)

Comment: Hello all, thank you for your replies. Actually, I'm really new in VBA, I just learned for 3 days, I will take into account your comments. Thanks

Comment: I want to write code that can copy paste the cells if the condition met, I was stuck, therefore I wanted try if my code was running well by highlighting the correct rows according to the condition that I put (Value = 20). The code that I posted is only the beginning of my code, I'm going to develop it further .